# JSON.net ContractResolver vs. JsonConverter

Tags: json.net

I've been working with JSON.net for a while.  I have written both custom converters and custom contract resolvers (generally from modifying examples on S.O. and the Newtonsoft website), and they work fine.

The challenge is, other than examples, I see little explanation as to when I should use one or the other (or both) for processing.  Through my own experience, I've basically determined that contract resolvers are simpler, so if I can do what I need with them, I go that way; otherwise, I use custom JsonConverters.  But, I further know both are sometimes used together, so the concepts get further opaque.

Questions:

1. Is there a source that distinguishes when to user one vs. the other?  I find the Newtonsoft documentation unclear as to how the two are differentiated or when to use one or the other.
2. What is the pipeline of ordering between the two?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Great question.  I haven't seen a clear piece of documentation that says when you should prefer to write a custom [`ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) or a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to solve a particular type of problem.  They really do different things, but there is some overlap between what kinds of problems can be solved by each.  I've written a fair number of each while answering questions on StackOverflow, so the picture has become a little more clear to me over time.  Below is my take on it.

### ContractResolver

A contract resolver is *always* used by Json.Net, and governs serialization / deserialization behavior at a broad level.  If there is not a custom resolver provided in the settings, then the [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) is used.  The resolver is responsible for determining:

- what *contract* each type has (i.e. is it a primitive, array/list, dictionary, dynamic, [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), plain old object, etc.);
- what properties are on the type (if any) and what are their names, types and accessibility;
- what [attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) have been applied (e.g. `[JsonProperty]`, `[JsonIgnore]`, `[JsonConverter]`, etc.), and
- how those attributes should affect the (de)serialization of each property (or class).

Generally speaking, if you want to customize some aspect of serialization or deserialization across a wide range of classes, you will probably need to use a `ContractResolver` to do it.  Here are some examples of things you can customize using a `ContractResolver`:

- Change the contract used for a type

  - [Serialize all Dictionaries as an Array of Key/Value Pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12751354/10263)
  - [Serialize ListItems as a regular object instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23973926/10263)
- Change the casing of property names when serializing

  - [Use camel case for all property names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22130431/10263)
  - [Camel case all property names except dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24143149/10263)
- Programmatically apply attributes to properties without having to modify the classes (particularly useful if you don't control the source of said classes)

  - [Globally use a JsonConverter on a class without the attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27332258/10263)
  - [Remap properties to different names defined at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38111298/10263)
  - [Allow deserializing to public properties with non-public setters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28802288/10263)
- Programmatically *unapply* (ignore) attributes that are applied to certain classes

  - [Optionally turn off the JsonIgnore attribute at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37371786/10263)
  - [Make properties which are marked as required (for SOAP) not required for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535858/10263)
- [Conditionally serialize](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) properties

  - [Ignore read-only properties across all classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18543482/10263)
  - [Skip serializing properties that throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20962316/10263)
- Introduce custom attributes and apply some custom behavior based on those attributes

  - [Encrypt specially marked string properties in any class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29196809/10263)
  - [Selectively escape HTML in strings during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32562381/10263)

### JsonConverter

In contrast to a `ContractResolver`, the focus of a `JsonConverter` is more narrow: it is really intended to handle serialization or deserialization for a single type or a small subset of related types.  Also, it works at a lower level than a resolver does.  When a converter is given responsibility for a type, it has complete control over how the JSON is read or written for that type: it directly uses [`JsonReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) and [`JsonWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm) classes to do its job.  In other words, it can change the *shape* of the JSON for that type.  At the same time, a converter is decoupled from the "big picture" and does not have access to contextual information such as the parent of the object being (de)serialized or the property attributes that were used with it.  Here are some examples of problems you can solve with a `JsonConverter`:

- Handle object instantiation issues on deserialization

  - [Deserialize to an interface, using information in the JSON to decide which concrete class to instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/10263)
  - [Deserialize JSON that is sometimes a single object and sometimes an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/10263)
  - [Deserialize JSON that can either be an array or a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21940989/10263)
  - [Skip unwanted items when deserializing from an array of mixed types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19700770/10263)
  - [Deserialize to an object that lacks a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23017716/10263)
- Change how values are formatted or interpretted

  - [Serialize decimal values as localized strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4721143/10263)
  - [Convert decimal.MinValue to an empty string and back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27063475/10263) (for use with a legacy system)
  - [Serialize dates with multiple different formats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17856580/10263)
  - [Ignore UTC offsets when deserializing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37318712/10263)
  - [Make Json.Net call `ToString()` when serializing a type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22354867/10263)
- Translate between differing JSON and object structures

  - [Deserialize a nested array of mixed values into a list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34047955/10263)
  - [Deserialize an array of objects with varying names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307062/10263)
  - [Serialize/deserialize a custom dictionary with complex keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32847117/10263)
  - [Serialize a custom IEnumerable collection as a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18579427/10263)
  - [Flatten a nested JSON structure into a simpler object structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21748635/10263)
  - [Expand a simple object structure into a more complicated JSON structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36201875/10263)
  - [Serialize a list of objects as a list of IDs only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24976779/10263)
  - [Deserialize a JSON list of objects containing GUIDs to a list of GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32184375/10263)
- Work around issues (de)serializing specific .NET types

  - [Serializing System.Net.IPAddress throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18668617/10263)
  - [Problems deserializing Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6854461/10263)

Comment: Wow that's a very thorough answer...   I would add a fews things after a week or so of testing a lot of aspects.

Comment: Exactly the clarifications and resources I needed. Thanks for all the hard work on this.

Comment: i know "thanks" comments are not really wanted, but this answer deserves one: thanks, especially for all the links!

Comment: Hi Brian. I was wondering if I could use one of these techniques to avoid having to decorate my Json. I am currently deserialising a pretty complex objects and I have to pollute my Jsons with things such as $type: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ClassName, Namespace]], mscorlib"

Comment: @progLearner Yes, almost certainly.  You're probably looking for something like [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/10263).  If you need more specific help than that, please [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).