# How to deserialize a json data array

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have this json file:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1557323147422,
  "change_id": 11687520784,
  "data": [
      [ "new", 5775.0, 16530.0 ],
      [ "new", 5774.5, 360.0 ]
  ]
}
```

I need to set up a class to deserialize it, but the data array is causing me a problem.

I tried to map data to:

```
List<(string, double, double)>
```

but that doesn't work.
List works, but then it's just pushing the problem one step away.

I can map it to

```
List<dynamic>
```

and then I get a list of JArray that I need to parse individually.

What I need is to be able to map it to some class that has a string and 2 doubles.

Comment: maybe `tuple` ?

Comment: @demo well he tried a tuple with `List<(string, double, double)>`

Comment: yes, that doesn't work:  Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Tuple`3[System.String,System.Double,System.Double]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: I can do a List<List<string>> but then I have to parse the doubles after that

Comment: JYou need to write your own ContractResolver for this transformation. And you cannot use Value Tuples instead of classic System.Tuple class in your code - JSON.NET cannot map it by name yet (see this: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1230 )

Comment: Here many examples of contracts which allow you to solve your task in a easy way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088492/json-net-contractresolver-vs-jsonconverter

Comment: @Dmitriy Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Nope. In the future if you will use .NET Core >= 3.0, pls, read about new MS .Net json serializer which will replace JSON.NET.

Comment: That is fundamentally a list of lists of values. You can use Json.net and do the serialization more by hand, but I doubt you will be able to get it to just deserialize a list into an object directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://json2csharp.com/

I generated this code:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public long timestamp { get; set; }
    public long change_id { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes, that's what I wrote about in the question, it just shifts the problem to parsing the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is still an array of `object` in JSON, it is neither a tuple nor a type.

So `List<List<object>>` (or `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>`) seems to be the only option.

Comment: or `object[][]` ;)