# How add default value to dictionary where value is empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary, .net-core

I have an `enum` property

```
public enum UserNotificationTypes
{
    Email,
    SMS,
    Push_Messages
}
```

and a model class

```
public class SaveUserSettingRequest
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> UserNotifications { get; set; } 
}
```

and my method is

```
 List<UserSetting> userSettings = new List<UserSetting>();

 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> settings in request.UserNotifications)
 {
      UserSetting usettings = new UserSetting();
      usettings.Name = $"{Constants.USER_NOTIFICATION}.{((UserNotificationTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserNotificationTypes), settings.Key)).ToString()}";
      usettings.Value = request.UserNotifications[settings.Key];
      usettings.UserId = userDetails.UserId;
      userSettings.Add(usettings);
  }
```

My request JSON looks like

```
{   
  "UserName": "xyz",
  "UserNotifications": {
    "Email": "true",
    "SMS": "true",
    "Push_Messages": "true"
  }
}
```

hear my functionality working fine.my problem is i want insert data with `false` in case key value is empty .

```
{

  "UserName": "xyz",
  "UserNotifications": {
    "Email": "",
    "SMS": "",
    "Push_Messages": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: prasad  above lines working  fine but getting an error at "true". request..like string does not contain definition request..

Comment: now working as per my requirement ..thank you prasad garu ..

Comment: since you are consuming Json data, you shall be able to apply a custom converter to convert the empty values as false when de-serialized. That way you don't mix non business logic with the main code

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `JsonConverter` implementation for your case, it is seamless way to achieve what you are trying to do since it will internally transform the Json during de-serialization without any extra piece of code in the business Logic. This is attribute based programming, which adds an additional conversion aspect to the property, in Read and Write Json any amount of custom logic can incorporated to work during serialization and de-serialization

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"UserName\":\"xyz\",\"UserNotifications\":{\"Email\":\"\",\"SMS\":\"\",\"Push_Messages\":\"\"}}";

    var result  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSetting>(json);

    result.Dump();
}

// Create a Custom JsonConverter
public class UserNotificationsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(UserNotifications).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    // Custom logic in the ReadJson
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
            var userNotificationObj = serializer.Deserialize<UserNotifications>(reader);

            userNotificationObj.Email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNotificationObj.Email) ? "false" : userNotificationObj.Email;
            userNotificationObj.SMS = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNotificationObj.SMS) ? "false" : userNotificationObj.SMS;
            userNotificationObj.Push_Messages = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNotificationObj.Push_Messages) ? "false" : userNotificationObj.Push_Messages;

            return userNotificationObj;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// UserSetting entity
public class UserSetting
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}

    // Decorate with the Custom Json Converter
    [JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(UserNotificationsConverter))]
    public UserNotifications UserNotifications {get; set;}
}

public class UserNotifications
{
    public string Email {get; set;}

    public string SMS {get; set;}

    public string Push_Messages {get; set;}
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome @CherryR, this is correct way to achieve it using programming, so in your actual code implement a converter and mange the conversion internally

Comment: This is right approach to fix issue at root - level, @CherryR This will help us to handle such situations in further development. +1 to you.

Comment: Thanks @PrasadTelkikar, check out the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088492/json-net-contractresolver-vs-jsonconverter for more information and difference between JsonConverter and the ContractResolver, which can be used at the class level

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to set `false`, if your `settings.Value` is empty, you can try below code

```
usettings.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Value) ? "false" : settings.Value;
```